# Recursive program can't calculate the sum

Tags: c, recursion

this is the input write in program 1, 3 , (2,4,6), 5, 7

and output should be

```
1+3

1+ ( (2+4)+(2+6)+(4+6))

1+5

1+7

3+ ( (2+4)+(2+6)+(4+6))

3+5

3+7

( (2+4)+(2+6)+(4+6)) +5

( (2+4)+(2+6)+(4+6))+7

5+7
```

and i am practicing recursion

so i write the code to calculate the sum of (2,4,6) first

here's my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
 int recursion(int* array,int i,int j,int size,int sum){
        if(i < size-1){
               if(j < size ){
                    printf("%d\n",array[i]+array[j]);
                    sum = sum+array[i]+array[j];
                    j++;
                    recursion(array,i,j,size,sum);

               }
               else{
                     printf("\n");
                     i++;
                     j=i+1;
                     recursion(array,i,j,size,sum);
               }
        }       
        return sum;
 }

int main(){
   int i=0,j=i+1,sum=0;
   int a[3]={2,4,6};

   int c =recursion(a,i,j,3,sum);
   printf("\n\n%d",c);
   return 0;
}
```

and i always get output of sum `6 (2+4)`

i don't know what's wrong with it? someone can help me?

Comment: You get 6\n8\n\n10\n\n\n6 as output. This is expected due to the way you move your indices and handle the returns (C is pass by value). In the "true" branch of the if for example you move j and keep i still, not sure if intentional. Fixing this code means to rewrite it ex novo, we can't do that. I'm voting to close.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Keeping ``i`` still is correct. I'd say the logic is fine. He's implementing a double ``for`` loop (where in the inner one ``i`` remains constant), via recursion.

Comment: @atturri, a double `for` for summing the elements of an array?

Comment: Yes, a double ``for``. He's not adding the elements. He's adding all possible pairs in the array. See his examples.

Comment: @atturi, Ok. So, please, take the time to edit the question to make the OP intent clearer. Thanks!

Comment: but how can i return the value of (2,4,6)'s sum, so that i can print out the1+3,

1+ ( (2+4)+(2+6)+(4+6)),

1+5,

1+7

Comment: Since the answer has been given to you and you aren't getting it I would recommend that the best solution is the step through with a debugger.  Of course, that would have been my suggestion if I had appeared here two hours ago and had the opportunity to be the first to answer/comment.

Comment: use double loop instead of recursion.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `recursion()` from inside `recursion()`, you're not doing anything with its result, so you're not adding the inner calculations to your final result. Each time you call `recursion()` (except from `main()`), do this:

```
sum = recursion(array,i,j,size,sum);
```

Comment: Thx, but do u know how can i calculate the sum?

Comment: You already did. You get ``6`` because you're outputting only the ``2+4`` sum. You're doing ``4+6`` and ``2+6`` internally, but not adding their results to the overall result.

Comment: Thx,but i tried sum=sum+recursion(array,i,j,size,sum),it's failed again,how can i add results to the overall result,can u teach me?